# How to configure ffmpeg under Javacv when using the FFmpegFrameGrabber to enable ZVBI

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I m new to ffmpeg

I found it easier to interact with it from Javafx when using the JavaCV project

I m successfully streaming from an RTSP protocol and I want to fine tune my player for better performance, to do so I need to activate some [options](https://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#ZVBI) but I have no idea how to achieve this configuration, since the `grabber.setOption(key, value);` is a key value signature where `grabber` is instance of `FFmpegFrameGrabber`.

Shortly, How to configure ffmpeg by code when using JavaCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I had a miss understanding of the concept

ffmpeg can be [configured](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md) to enable some support (modules) like the ZVBI to do so you have to refer to the install documentation of ffmpeg by using the `./configure` to fine tune you have the following [answer that will guide you](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/1356#issuecomment-565361081) to use the api of ffmpeg in opencv to use the enabled modules in ffmpeg by the tuning value

Shortly the flow is

1. Read about a module
2. choose the best tuning values depending on your needs
3. refer to answer to choose the best api call to set the values

Thanks